# Joomla 4: no need for Route::_($url)?

Tags: development, joomla-4.x, router, best-practices

I am using this on a custom component:

```
$url = index.php?option=com_content&view=article&catid=427&id=15106
```

Both

```
echo $url;
echo Route::_($url);
```

will output a friendly url.

I'm guessing this is coming from some J4 plugin and I should always use `echo Route::_($url);` for good practice, right?

Answer (score 1):

Both of your assumptions are correct. Non-SEF URLs are converted to SEF by `System - SEF` plugin. But you should use SEF URLs in PHP code whenever possible. This will ensure proper URLs when the plugin is disabled and slightly improve performance when the plugin is enabled. For in-content URLs (e.g. URLs inside article text) it's the opposite. Non-SEF URLs should be used to prevent breaking when content item aliases or menu structures are changed.